# Maven purge local dependency tags are not working in pom.xml

Tags: maven, dependencies, include, purge

I am working on a maven integrated project . I want only one dependency to be refreshed in local maven repository. I need  my pom.xml to include the  mvn cmd =>  mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -Dincludes= < artifactId >

```
   <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>purge-local-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>purge-local-repository</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <resolutionFuzziness>artifactId</resolutionFuzziness>
                            <includes>
                                <include><groupId>:<artifactId></include>
                            </includes>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
         </executions>

    </plugin>
```

First time when i ran , it downloaded maven-dependency-jar into repo folder . But it didn't delete and download again the  jar that has its artifactId listed  inside include tag. 
Please help me in identifying where is the mistake in the plugin definition. What  could be the cause of maven to ignore this plugin goal ?
I do not see any error  while executing the  build script.

--
Thanks

** After several runs of the script , i find that the control is not going to this block of plugin . Hence this piece of script is not getting executed . It is weird . Do i need to some where call the goal defined inside execution tag ? Or does the maven executes all plugin tags sequentially by itself ? I must tell here that i have checked skipTests = True in the IDE ->maven window. Any help will be helpful

(1) ** After keeping plugin tag outside `<pluginManagement>` like => `<build>/<plugins>/<mydefinition of plugin>`

Error is below:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:purge-local-repository (purge-local-dependencies) on project lvb_war_module: 
Execution purge-local-dependencies of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:purge-local-repository failed:
Unable to load the mojo 'purge-local-repository' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1'
due to an API incompatibility:org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException:
org/apache/maven/plugins/dependency/PurgeLocalRepositoryMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I am using maven-compiler-plugin 2.3.2 and maven-dependency-plugin is version 3.1.1. Maven installed on my system is 3.2.5 .

Please help in identifying the problem.

--

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if it's an unfortunate copy-paste error, but 'resolutionFuziness' is spelled with two z's.

Comment: What kind of artifacts are these? Releases or SNAPSHOT' s?

Comment: Just verified , in the project pom.xml it is 'resolutionFuzziness' .  The jar in the desired artifact is custom jar . <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> is written in its dependency tree .

Comment: after several runs of the script , i find that the  control is not going to this block of plugin . Hence this piece of script is not getting executed . It is weird . Do i need to some where  call the goal defined inside execution tag ? Or does the maven  executes  all plugin tags sequentially by itself ?  I must tell here  that i have  checked  skipTests = True in the IDE ->maven window. Any help will be helpful.

Comment: Did you specify the plugin above within a `<pluginManagement>` block? It's a common mistake.

Comment: You don't need things like this of you like to update SNAPSHOT's...a simple `mvn -U clean package` will update the SNAPSHOT's versions to the most recent one...(last which has been deployed to a repository manager...)...This is related to the [update policy](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) which can be configured in you `settings.xml` by default it is 24 hours which is usually ok..but sometimes not.

Comment: Thanks for inputs  . I have two points 1) i do not want all the SNAPSHOTs libs to get updated .Only what is specified inside include tag need to get updated . 2) i need to do it through pom.xml . cli usage is not possible in my case.   Over all , What is the  issue in that  syntax  ?  All the Plugin tags are  inside plugins tag , that is inside  pluginManagement .

Comment: Ok, plugins within a `<pluginManagement>` block don't get executed automatically (it works in the same way as `<dependencyManagement>`). You should try to move this plugin to `<build>/<plugins>`.

Comment: Hi Daniel , i tried the way you suggested. I have  edited the  post  at block  (1) ** .with a detailed  error that i got  after executing it.

Comment: Yeah, you get that because the plugin is compiled with Java 7 and you are using something older. `mvn --version` will tell you which JRE you are using. I highly recommend upgrading your JRE.